# Problem with importing javafx packages: the type ... is not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm working on a project in Eclipse and I want to make use of JavaFX for my GUI. I installed JavaFX and I added it to my project library. However, every time I try to import packages, e.g.

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;`
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
```

then it reads : The type ... is not accessible.

I'm totally new to programming in Java so I have little experience. Can someone please explain in detail how this can be resolved?

[image]

Comment: Given the presence of `module-info.java`, you use a modular project, and you need to declare the necessary dependencies in the `module-info.java` file. Alternatively, you need to remove `module-info.java`.

Comment: Java version: Java version 8 Update 271. Eclipse version: 2020-09. I installed JavaFX from Eclipse Marketplace; e(fx)clipse 3.6.0 . For the {module-info.java}, there is no content. It just reads {module basicprogramming {
}}, which is the name of my project.

Comment: EDIT: removing the module-info.java worked!

Comment: Then you could use the information from the first comment and write up the answer to your own question with a bit of explanation, as actually you found the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example module-info.java.

```
module ships {
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires javafx.web;
    exports ships;
    //opens ...;
}
```

With java-8 simply remove module-info.java as it still is not modular.

For JavaFX (OpenJFX) a newer java would be better, and then use the advantages of modular java.

For library management ("dependencies") use the **maven** (or **gradle**) build infrastructure.